# Get custom attribute value using Next() by Class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attr, custom-attributes

I'm looking to get the value of a custom attribute in an image by class, using next().

```
$("#chkSell").live('change',function(){
     var posType = $(this).next('img[class="qtyImgDD"]').attr('posType');
});
<div class="Sell" style="width: 47px;"><input type="checkbox" fund-id="1" id="chkSell" class="_1"/></div>
<div class="Buy" style="width: 47px;"><input type="checkbox" fund-id="1" id="chkBuy" class="_1"/></div>
<div class="BuySelllbl" style="width: 10px;"><label class="lblBuySell_1" fund-id="1">&nbsp;</label></div>
<div class="Amt" style="width: 116px;"><input type="textbox" fund-id="1" id="AmtValue" size="8" disabled="disabled"/></div>
<div class="QtyType" style="width: 55px;"><label class="lblQtyType" fund-id="1" ddclass="_1">D</label>&nbsp;

<img src="/Applications/Images/ModelManagement/DropDown_Disabled.gif" fund-id="1" posType="MutualFund" class="qtyImgDD" disabled="disabled" ddclass="_1"/></div>
```

What i want is when someone clicks on the chkSell checkbox and enacts the change() function to get the posType attribute value from the  on the bottom?

Comment: what problem you are facing.??

Comment: why would you downvote my point when i clearly asked a question and expressed my issue with the proper code references and HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple minor things that you may want to change. Switch "live" to "on", switch "next" to "nextAll", change "img[class="qtyImgDD"]" to img.qtyImgDD.

```
$("#chkSell").on('change',function(){
     var posType = $(this).parent().nextAll('.QtyType').find('img.qtyImgDD').attr('posType');
});
```

`Next` is only the immediate sibling, where as `nextAll` is all following siblings.

Also, the markup you have doesn't have the elements you're targeting as direct siblings. So you'll need to traverse through their parents.

---

Ref:

- http://api.jquery.com/next/
- http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Comment: this works great, thank you very much for your help i'll do more reading on the nextAll documentation, i wasn't familiar with that.